# rails / rspec / capybara - infinite 'waiting for page...' after clicking button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

After the fields are filled in and the button is pressed the browsers (opened by the script) says "waiting for page at 127...."   but it never goes anywhere (I waited over 30 mins).   I'm testing on a ubuntu 10.04 box.  Any ideas?

```
describe "GET 'new'", :js => true do
    it "will log in" do
      @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
      puts @admin
      puts @admin.attributes
      visit '/'
      fill_in 'user_login', :with => @admin.email
      fill_in 'user_password', :with => @admin.password
      click_on 'Sign in'
      response.should be_success      
    end    

    it "should be successful" do
      visit '/things/new'
      page.should have_xpath('//form')
    end

  end
```

Comment: Are you using capybara with which driver? on which platform?

My guess at this moment is JavaScript is not working as you expect.
You probably want to run `save_and_open_page` between actions to verify whether you correctly have the page.

Comment: I use the defaults, which I think is selenium (firefox says WebDriver in the bottom right corner)

Comment: this is helpful, at least its telling me that my firefox profile is missing.

Comment: Then, you can verify each step with debugger whether capybara actually fill the forms. Depends on your platform, you can try `capybara-webkit` which is a headless driver and works very well.
Link: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit

Comment: I'm still finding the same issue.   It just goes in to "waiting" after the 'Sign in ' button is clicked.

Comment: Did you try any simple form without JavaScript first? Also, I'm curious whether the Selenium actually hit the button and some request sent to the server, or it is sent but have not gotten reply.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to check the `response` in a Capybara integration test. After `sign_in`, check instead for some success message in the new page, eg. `page.should have_content 'Welcome!`.